# First time using button code

Tags: swift, button

I have this variable

```
var taxableTotalText = String(28)
```

it is populated from a second view controller, it works well except when you use the app for the first time, if the string is blank it crashes the app. I have tried

```
if taxableTotalText.isEmpty  {
    NSUserDefaults().setObject("0.00", forKey: String(28))
}
```

but it didn't work.

I would like to use some code like this

```
if TaxableAllowancesBtn "Has never been pushed" {     
    NSUserDefaults().setObject("0.00", forKey: String(28))
}
else {
       //do nothing
}
TaxableTotal.text = NSUserDefaults().stringForKey(taxableTotalText)
```

but "Has never been pushed" needs to be some real swift coding.
At the moment i am just using

```
NSUserDefaults().setObject("0.00", forKey: String(28))
```

it stops my app from crashing but also forces my label to be "0.00" every time I reopen the app. A simple segue and back fixes the issue but its bugging me.
Can someone please swap my english for swift, or suggest a better way to solve this issue.
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the "??" [nil coalescing operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID72) to return a default value instead of nil.

```
TaxableTotal.text = NSUserDefaults().stringForKey("yourKey") ?? "0.00"
```

Comment: Thank you. This is perfect, so much better than than path my mind was taking me